# angularjs typehead with toArrayFilter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs `typehead` for auto-complete:

```
<input class="form-control reason-select" type="text" ng-model="selectedName" typeahead="name.kod as name.value for name in List | toArray | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
```

based on [typehead example](http://jsfiddle.net/wholypantalones/H7LA4/) and using `toArray` filter beacuse `List` is a `object` and not an `array` ref - [notarray](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray).
`List` -

```
{
  "0": {
    "kod": 107,
    "value": "john doe", 
  },
  "1": {
    "kod": 3994,
    "value": "jane doe",
  }
}
```

It works fine but as I choose a option the `kod` is displayed instead of the `value`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typeahead="name.kod as name.value for name in List"

means "name.kod" will be shown to the user but "name.value" is saved in the $viewValue.

So in your case, it is working perfect but you need to reverse the variables if you want to show the value i.e.jane doe but save the kod i.e.3994 .
Hope it helps

Comment: well you are right but when switching kod and value the auto-complete shows the kod instead of value.

Comment: use can try https://gist.github.com/awgreenblatt/4499728 for using typeahead with array of objects, but you will have to handle that in the js part